# Why is 180 rotation disabled on android devices?

Tags: auto-rotation

I managed to get around the limitation using an app (Rotation Lock Adaptive) but meanwhile it still has me stumped as to why you can't use a tablet upside down (I prefer to have usb cable out of way when changing or tethered) any ideas?

Comment: It's not "on Android devices", it's "on *some* Android devices". The device manufacturer chooses whether to allow this when they do the software integration.

Comment: Ok maybe not all but the majority (I don't recall a device I've owned that didn't).. I'm just wondering about the rationale